# Passing array through average method, resulting in low percent

Tags: java

For some reason the average is being populated wrong when I pass the array to the method I get a really low percent. It almost seems like since the Array shotsMade is only recording integers for made shots and not misses it is not calculating off the right base.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int myGameCounter = 1;  
    int shotCount = 0;
    int shotCount1 = 0;
    int [] shotsMade = new int [5];
    int sum = 0;

    System.out.print("Enter Player's Free Throw Percentage: ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int percent = input.nextInt();


    //Game #1
    System.out.println("Game " + myGameCounter + ":");
    Random r = new Random();
    myGameCounter++;
    shotCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
        boolean in = tryFreeThrow(percent);
        if (in) {
        shotCount++;
        System.out.print("In" + " ");
        }
        else {
        System.out.print("Out" + " ");
        }
    }

    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Free throws made: " + shotCount + " out of 10");
    shotsMade[0]= shotCount;

        //Game #2
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Game" + myGameCounter + ":");
    myGameCounter++;
    shotCount1 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
        boolean in = tryFreeThrow(percent);
        if (in) {
        shotCount1++;
        System.out.print("In" + " ");
        }
        else {
        System.out.print("Out" + " ");
        }   
    }
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Free throws made: " + shotCount1 + " out of 10");
    shotsMade[1]= shotCount1;

    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Summary:");



    System.out.println("Best game: " + max(shotsMade)); 
    System.out.println("Total Free Throws Made: " + sum(shotsMade) + " " + "out of 20");
    System.out.println("Average Free Throw Percentage: " + average(shotsMade) +"%");
```

}//main

```
public static boolean tryFreeThrow(int percent) {
    Random r = new Random();
    int number = r.nextInt(100);
    if (number > percent){ 
     return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public static float average(int nums[]) {
    int total = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<nums.length; i++) {
        total = total + nums[i];
    }
    float f = (total / nums.length);
    return (float)total /(float)nums.length;
}

public static int sum(int nums[]) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<nums.length; ++i) {
        sum += nums[i];
    }
    return (int)sum;
}

public static int max(int nums[]) {
    int max=nums[0];
    for (int i=1; i<nums.length; i++) {
        if (nums[i] > max) 
            max = nums[i];
    }
    return max;
}
```

}//class

Comment: Firstly, your average won't be accurate. You're dividing two `int` values. One of them needs to be casted to a `float` or `double` to achieve any precision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calculating the avarage of 5 numbers but you only set 2. So if all shots hit your array will look like this: `10, 10, 0, 0, 0` and the avarage will be 4.

Comment: I have added the other 3 games to make a total of 5. I can now hit 50/50 and still yields 10%. Do i need to change (float) to (int)? or should i just have it multiple the final answer by *10?

Comment: You are not calculating the average percentage, you are calculating the absolute average. The average of `10,10,10,10,10`is 10. To calculate the average percentage you need to calculate the percentage of each game and calculate the average of that. `(10/10 + 10/10 + 10/10 + 10/10 + 10/10)/5 = 1 = 100%`

Answer (score 1):

Old issue, you are using integer arithmetic `total / nums.length` with returns you an `int` value. You later assign it to a `float`, but the value already has been truncated.

Just change one of the values to `float` *before* the division, v.g. `((float) total) / num`

Comment: I have tried this and it still give the wrong percent. i made 8/20 shots and it says its 1.8%. If I hit 20/20 its 4%.

Answer (score 0):

Among others, your expression

```
float f = (total / nums.length);
```

will yield an inaccurate result.

Both `total` and `nums.length` are integers, and any operation between integers always results in an integer.

Example: if total=10 and nums.length=3, you'd expect the result to be 3.333... but actually the result is just 3. Only after that do you cast it to a float, resulting in 3.0.

To get the required result, you need to cast both integers to floats before dividing:

```
float f = (float) total / (float) nums.length;
```